# How do I prevent OS X from making ".filename" files?

Tags: snow-leopard, file, macos

I'm not sure of the consistency but sometimes OS X makes hidden `.filename` files where `filename` is a name of another file in the same directory. I want to know how to disable this since USBs I insert and copy / move files to / from keep having this and it's annoying to have to delete them every time I plug the USB onto a non-Mac computer.

Answer (score 2):

What format is the volume in? If you mean the AppleDouble files that start with `._`, they are not normally created on HFS volumes. They are used to store metadata like extended attributes, ACLs, and resource forks on non-HFS volumes.

You can delete the `._` files with `find`:

```
find /Volumes/volume -name ._\* -delete
```

If the volume is in an HFS format, you can use `dot_clean` to remove the `._` files after merging the metadata stored in them with the metadata stored in native formats:

```
dot_clean /Volumes/volume
```

Comment: The volume is formatted in FAT32.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this (with a commercial program though) seems to be to use [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/) (hat tip to [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/212907)). Note that BlueHarvest does not prevent the creation of these files. It continuously monitors non-Mac drives and cleans them up. It can also be used to manually clean up a volume/folder/file.

For other alternatives (some with limitations), see:
[Is there any way to prevent a Mac from creating dot underscore files? - from superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/212896/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-a-mac-from-creating-dot-underscore-files)
[BlueHarvest Alternatives for Mac OS X](http://alternativeto.net/software/blueharvest/?platform=mac)

You can also use the solution below to replace the standard `umount` (unmount) program with a wrapper script to clean up these files when you eject the MSDOS formatted drive:
["Automatically delete Mac OS X dot files from MS-DOS filesystems" - Feb 07, '11](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110204124029798)

Comment: Is there a system-level setting of preventing this? Because I'm pretty positive, this wasn't happening before. (Say, a year or so ago.)

Comment: Nothing that works on all kinds of (hidden) files that Finder does not show on HFS+ volumes. Did you use HFS+ formatted drives before and then switched to MSDOS in the last year or so?

Comment: Not really, all USBs I've used are commonly formatted in FAT32.